# Adding other files to a Git folder

Tags: git

I have a project that has lost of surrounding files that arn't code or with the release of the software.

Think Technical Documentation or PSD files.

Should I add these to the folder that gets committed to Git?

Comment: In general, technical documentation is fine to store, since it's (presumably) just text files, whereas I wouldn't store the PSDs in git, especially if they're changing often. But it really depends on your specific scenario here.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the input il miss out the PSDs, there are a lot of txt files but Its the large word document (docx) that i'm a bit dubious about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSD are binary and big files. You should try to avoid storing such a files in git.

Instead take a look on this project:
https://git-lfs.github.com/

Its for such a case where you have big files to deal with.